# How to skip exception raised in INSERT statement?

Tags: sql, postgresql, insert, constraints

When I run the following SQL code:

```
INSERT INTO table
(column1, column1)
SELECT column1, column2
FROM other_table
WHERE column2 = 'foo'
ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING;
```

I get

```
PG::CheckViolation: ERROR:
new row for relation "table" violates
check constraint "tables_column1_valid_first_char"
```

How can I skip rows violating that check constraint?

I tried

```
INSERT INTO table
(column1, column1)
SELECT column1, column2
FROM other_table
WHERE column2 = 'foo'
ON CONFLICT  ON CONSTRAINT tables_column1_valid_first_char DO NOTHING;
```

But it fails with

```
PG::WrongObjectType: ERROR:
constraint in ON CONFLICT clause has no associated index
```

The constraint looks as following:

```
ADD CONSTRAINT tables_column1_valid_first_char
  CHECK (SUBSTRING(text, 1,1) ~* '^[a-zàâçéèêëîïôûùüÿæœ]');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ON CONFLICT` only deals with unique constraints, it doesn't work for check constraints (or foreign key constraints).

You need to exclude those rows by applying a WHERE clause:

```
INSERT INTO table (column1, column1)
SELECT column1, column2
FROM other_table
WHERE column2 = 'foo'
  and SUBSTRING(column1, 1,1) ~* '^[a-zàâçéèêëîïôûùüÿæœ]'
ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING;
```

Comment: Ok, I thought there's some other way, but this will work as well, thanks!